# Why does Se-82 undergo double beta decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, particle-physics, radioactivity

Looking at the decay chain, I saw it undergoes double beta decay.  How is it feasible for something to undergo a simultaneous double decay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for double beta decay to be the preferred mode are that the energy (mass) of the three states

- The initial nucleus (m)
- The would-be single-beta-decay daughter plus the electron and the anti-neutrino (s)
- The double-beta-decay daughter plus the two electrons and the two anti-neutrinos (d)

have a relationship like

$$ E_d < E_m < E_s \,.$$

The result is that it is not possible for a single decay to proceed (there is not enough energy) but it *is* possible for a double decay to happen (though it will be a slow process).